# sql - update two key columns without conflict

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-update

I want to to update a column from table patient, and add a prefix before all its fields, like

```
update patient
set contactdetailsID = '99999'+ contactdetailsID
where patient.id = 5294
```

So, row with id = 5294, will have the same value in column contactdetailsID with prefix 99999.

```
Before  |    After
012345      99999012345
```

the issue i am facing is that patient.contactdetailsID is the foreign key for another table "contactdetails".

So i get the following error.

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 UPDATE statement conflicted with
>   COLUMN FOREIGN KEY constraint 'ContactDetails_Patient_FK1'. The
>   conflict occurred in database 'A', table 'ContactDetails',
>   column 'id'. The statement has been terminated.
>
> (0 row(s) affected)

How can i make that change? I want to change both patient.contactdetailsID and its key Contactdetails.ID, with the same prefix in order not to lose the connection between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporary disable the Foreign-Key Constraint using:

```
ALTER TABLE *Tablename*
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT *ForeinKey_Name*;
```

and update both the ContactDetails Table and Patient Table.

But make sure that you enable the ForeignKey afterwards!

To enable a Foreign Key use

```
ALTER TABLE *Tablename*
CHECK CONSTRAINT *ForeinKey_Name*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in your table.
[see MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#idm47546182431648)

Comment: as far as i can see, i have to create the table with the cascade property from the beginning. In my case the tables are already created and have data.

Comment: You have to drop the constraint and recreate it with the `ON UPDATE` statement then, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11469101/3157536).